# AngularJS forEach not working on $http response

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Getting the values in response as:

```
[{
  "Pf": "something1",
  "label": ""
}, {
  "Pf": "something1",
  "label": ""
}]
```

#### JS

```
$scope.display = false;

$scope.getPanel = $http({
  mode: 'cors',
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/url/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).success(function(response) {

  $scope.original = function() {

    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
      if (value == "something1") {
        dispaly = false;
      } else if (value == "something2") {
        display = false;
      } else {
        display = true;
      }
    });
    return display;
  };
});
```

#### HTML

```
<td>
    <img src="image.png" uib-tooltip="{{status}}" ng-show="original()"/>
</td>
```

not getting key and value from response

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you have a typo `dispaly = false;`

Comment: m not getting values and key from response

Comment: Any feedback ASM?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you do have an error in if display writing dispaly instead display.

Secondly, the angular foreach second argument is a function taking as first argument the iterator on your collection. Here, your collection is composed of two object, so on each iteration, value will be an object , for example :

```
{
  "Pf": "something1",
  "label": ""
}
```

So, if you want to test if it is equal to "something1", you have to compare it with value.pf and not value.

You also need to call response.data because response is a structure that stores different informations about your request answer.

To finish, i advice you to store the value display in your scope and bind it on ng-show directive like this :

**JS**

```
$scope.display = false;

$http({
  mode: 'cors',
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/url/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).success(function(response) {

    angular.forEach(response.data, function(value, key) {
      if (value.pf == "something1") {
        $scope.display= false;
      } else if (value.pf == "something2") {
        display = false;
      } else {
        display = true;
      }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <img src="image.png" uib-tooltip="{{status}}" ng-show="display"/>
</td>
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: getting response.data as undefined.

Comment: So your configuration for http request is bad.... I supposed that your api doesn't end with "/url/" .... If the url does not exist, response will never be defined.
More of that, mode: 'cors' doesnt exist as a parameter of $http method...
If you have the possibility, make sure that your api is called by adding a log into your web server method. If it is not reached, you have to check your configuration here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Note that `display` get overwritten on each loop. Ensure your logic is correct. While `display` is an `$scope` variable you need to access this param by using `$scope.display` instead of `display`. Your codes should look like this:

#### View

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="ApplicationController">
   <h1>Output: {{ display }}</h1>
   <div ng-show="display">
     Now I'm here
   </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('ApplicationController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.display = false;

  $scope.getPanel = $http({
    mode: 'cors',
    method: 'GET',
    url: './data.json',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).success(function(response) {
    original(response);
  });


  function original (response) {
    angular.forEach(response, function(value, key) {
      if (value.Pf == "something1") {
        $scope.display = false;
      } else if (value.Pf == "something2") {
        $scope.display = false;
      } else {
        $scope.display = true;
      }
    });

    console.log($scope.display);
  };
});
```

--> **[Demo plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/UCm8XG1vOQpQvNzNhKNt?p=preview)**

Comment: $scope.display; getting overwrite

Comment: @ASM Sorry, I do not understand you. Please explain your problem.

Comment: I am not getting correct value. i am getting object in value insteat i want single value from object response

Comment: @ASM use the chrome/firefox dev tools and see your object, see if you're getting the data from the request

Comment: @ASM I added a full working example in my codes. Please check the demo plnkr and compare it with your solution.

Comment: In html instead of variable display's value i need to show/ hide image when value is true/false.

Comment: @ASM please check my example carefully. There is an `show/hide` logic near `<div ng-show="display">Now I'm here </div>` . The output is just for debugging. Thanks

Comment: @ASM any feedback?

Comment: @ASM so please create a fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: value is returning the object and angular.foreach is working for every element in that object but i want that it should work for single key:value pair for example pf:something1 and if value is pf.something1 then it should return false otherwise it should return true.

Comment: @ASM its hard to solve your problem if you are not going to write down all your specs/requirements. Soo, please create a plnkr/fiddle to reproduce your problem. Thank you.

Comment: @ASM any feedback?